# BroadcastReceiver too slow?

Tags: android, android-intent, service, broadcastreceiver

this is what I've gotten so far:

Service running which is keeping up two connections (to two different servers), registering a `BroadcastReceiver`. The `BroadcastReceiver` is receiving my commands, which I want to send through the sockets. Working so far.
But: If I send "more" commands in a short time span (eg multiple commands in 1 sec) the `BroadcastReceiver` does not receive them - is the broadcast receiver too slow? Would it help to start a different thread in onReceive for handling the extra data?
Or should I go back to binding the service and passing direct commands to that object?

Would this be possible? -> Service running in background, registering a `BroadcastReceiver`, but also bound to an activity - it should still be the same service "object", right?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but instead of registering the broadcast receiver within the service code, it may be worth registering it within the Android Manifest may make it a bit quicker. This is how I usually do it and never find the broadcast to be slow or not received.